# Tips in saving user details during Social Media Authentication (Laravel Socialite)

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, laravel-socialite, social-media

Can you give me some tips in saving user details during social media authentication. Should i save the directly to the users table, or create a new table for social authentications? Data synchronization is good but if there an instances like:

1. An existing email address when login / register via social media?
2. Security issues about tokens etc.

How can i handle this scenario?

Comment: Best practices are opinionated as such, this question will be closed. Consider taking the [tour].

Comment: i've just edit the question.